# Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar toggle button with different icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By using Twitter Bootstrap 3, I want to create an additional navbar for mobile.

In navbar I will put 2 toggle buttons in each side of bar. Left button will have classical "three bar" icon, and right button will have a different icon inside. I want right button to have "[.glyphicon .glyphicon-comment](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)" inside it. If the user clicks the button it will also toggle for second menu. I can toggle for the menu but icon can't be changed ?

I couldn't put any other icon inside right toggle button ? (I also need the "some link" text to be centered in navbar)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/WPfe3/2/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top visible-xs" role="navigation" id="">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex2-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <i class="icon-user"></i>
    </button> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="text-align:center;" href="">Some link here centered</a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">AAAA 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">AAAA 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">AAAA 3</a>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex2-collapse">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">BBBB 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">BBBB 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">BBBB 3</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/WPfe3/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[SEE THE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7KdD4/4/)**

You forget to add `bootstrap-glyphicons.css`  in your jsfiddle demo.
Then Replace this

```
<i class="icon-user"></i>
```

With

```
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="color:#fff"></i>
```

And then to get your link in center you need to remove the class `navbar-brand` from your `a` tag. And then wrap your link with div and then apply `text-align:center` and some `padding` to get the link in center.

Comment: Well, but it seems like left and right buttons are not horizontally aligned. Left one is upper than right one. I check it by changing css file: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/7KdD4/1/ Also "some text" is not aligned with buttons.

Comment: Also "some linked" is sticked to the top of navbar. Not vertically aligned. Adding "margin-top" didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by changing the icon span,

Instead of,

```
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

Use like,

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" style="color:#fff"></span>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3QWSM/)

Comment: Note that two buttons aren't vertically aligned. http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/3QWSM/1/

Comment: Add some height also ``.navbar-toggle {
 max-height:35px;
}`` http://jsfiddle.net/3QWSM/2/

Comment: ``<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" style="color:#fff;margin-top:-5px"></span>``

Comment: "Some text" appears not to be centered horizontally ?